# How can I add Core Animation framework to my Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I just can't find that framework for adding it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 31):

Add the QuartzCore framework. It contains CoreAnimation.

Answer (score 10):

Also, make sure that you do an

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

before using any Core-Animation-specific classes, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the `QuartzCore` framework to your project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on your project in project navigator.
2. Click on the target.
3. Click on "build phases" tab.
4. Expand "Link Binary with Libraries".
5. Click "+" to add.