# High-resolution timer for iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, timer, high-resolution-clock

I'm looking for high-resolution timing code for iPhone, in order to do some performance timings.  I'd like to write code like this:

```
HighResolutionTimer* myTimer = [[HighResolutionTimer alloc]init];
[myTimer start];
[self doSomeLengthyOperation];
NSLog( @"doSomeLengthyOperation took %f seconds", [myTimer elapsedTime] );
```

Comment: Why not just use `getrusage()`?  Anything that works in C will work in Objective-C.

Comment: Because there's a perfectly good Cocoa method for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Look into mach_absolute_time() in the mach/mach_time.h header.

Don't use NSDate.  NSDate isn't even guaranteed to not go backwards occasionally, when ntp does its thing.

(Devices can have clock drift.  If the iOS device drifts fast a few seconds, then when NTP corrects this drift, you will see the clock suddenly go backwards a few seconds.  Very bad for timing use.  mach_time uses a counter that doesn't ever get corrected by NTP, thus can't go backwards, thus is far better for timing.)

Comment: `NSDate` just returns a double that counts the seconds since Jan 1 2001.  For stopwatch timing, a negative time just won't occur, so I see no need for the overhead of bringing `mach_absolute_time()` into your code -- [both implemented here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12553393/111307).

Comment: @bobobobo : The device's count of seconds since Jan 1 2001 occasionally gets corrected backwards by NTP.  So it can be non-monotonic on any given device that has a clock crystal that sometimes drifts fast, plus a network connection that can correct this drift.

Comment: I ended up using mach_absolute_time().  I found a little class using it, [here](http://zpasternack.blogspot.com/2012/07/high-resolution-timing-in-cocoa.html).

Comment: @howpaw2 That is a very fine point, you should work that explanation of drifting clocks into your answer.  Practically, I could see this showing up as a very strange bug a developer would have a really, really hard time finding, or even repeating.

Answer (score 16):

A better option is [`CACurrentMediaTime()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime?language=objc) which uses `mach_absolute_time()` but converts it to a [`CFTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cftimeinterval) (i.e., time in seconds as a double) for you.

Comment: Requires [`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729094).

Answer (score 8):

Here's my answer for clock timers using both `mach_absolute_time()`, based on compute method [shown here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html), and `NSDate`.  The are actually the same in terms of accuracy.

## Mach version

```
double machGetClockS()
{
  static bool init = 0 ;
  static mach_timebase_info_data_t tbInfo ;
  static double conversionFactor ;
  if(!init)
  {
    init = 1 ;
    // get the time base
    mach_timebase_info( &tbInfo ) ;
    conversionFactor = tbInfo.numer / (1e9*tbInfo.denom) ; // ns->s
  }

  return mach_absolute_time() * conversionFactor ; // seconds
}

double machGetClockDiffS()
{
  static double lastTime = 0;

  double currentTime = machGetClockS() ;

  double diff = currentTime - lastTime ;

  lastTime = currentTime ; // update for next call

  return diff ; // that's your answer
}
```

## NSTimeInterval version

```
double getClockS()
{
  return [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] ; // NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds 
}

double getClockDiffS()
{
  static double lastTime = 0 ;

  double currentTime = getClockS() ;

  double diff = currentTime - lastTime ;

  lastTime = currentTime ; // update for next call

  return diff ; // that's your answer
}
```

## Results:

Note the resolution on both of these is really good.

```
IOS SIMULATOR, running frame rate counts (in milliseconds (*1000.0))

MACH_ABS_TIME / NSTimeIntervals
58.557001 / 58.552980
40.558007 / 40.562987
52.207822 / 52.200019
33.742197 / 33.742011
38.498912 / 38.504004
48.872679 / 48.868001
45.012602 / 45.011997
57.858432 / 57.865977
25.044615 / 25.038004


IPAD HARDWARE SAMPLINGS:
33.415041 / 33.416033
33.240167 / 33.239007
33.357542 / 33.357978
33.302833 / 33.302009
33.506750 / 33.509016
33.582250 / 33.582985
33.233958 / 33.232987
33.239042 / 33.237994
```

<sub>*If you look at the edit history of this post, you can see the danger of using `float` in the place of a `double`!</sub>

Comment: You forgot to add  init = true; in machGetClockS().

Comment: Not a good test of time resolution, since you tested without wireshark monitoring for any NTP network connections, which can sometimes really mess with the NSDate results.

Answer (score 6):

Use `NSTimeInterval startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` to get a start time, and then `NSLog (@"Operation took %f seconds.", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - startTime);` at the end.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!  I didn't realize NSDate had this level of precision.